# Prove that $\forall M \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R}): \enspace M^2-(Tr(M))M \in Vect(I_2)$

Tags: matrices

> Prove that $\forall M \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R}): \enspace M^2-(Tr(M))M \in Vect(I_2)$

How can I prove this **without** using Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: You can verify $M^2-(\mathrm{tr}\,M)M+(\det M)I_2=0$ for $2\times2$ matrices $M=[\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}]$ without using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem very simply by direct computation: square the matrix, plug its trace and determinant in the equation, add em up and get the zero matrix. Did you do this already? If so, what's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $M=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$.

Then $M^2-Tr(M)M=\pmatrix{a^2+bc&ab+bd\\ca+cd&cb-d^2}-\pmatrix{a(a+d)&b(a+d)\\c(a+d)&d(a+d)}$

$=\pmatrix{bc-ad&0\\0&bc-ad}=(bc-ad)I_2.$

Comment: it's -$\det(M)I_2$

Comment: I wonder what the notation $\text{Vect}(I_2)$ stands for?

Comment: @Nicholas:   may be vector space spanned by $I_2$ (scalar multiples of $2\times2$ identity matrix)

Comment: Thats what I thought as well

Comment: $Vect(A)$ is a vector space (linear combinations of elements of A). In this case, it is $\alpha I_2$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ since $A=\{I_2\}$